# How to use a vue array inside a quote?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I was trying to access a vue array inside a quote like this

```
<div v-for="category in categories">
        <a href="{{category.link}}">Links</a>
</div>
```

its doesnt seem to work. Then i tried taking the code out of the quote`<a href="">{{category.link}}</a>` this works fine .  Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must bind your attributes when they are from Vue variables.

```
<div v-for="category in categories">
    <a :href="category.link">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt work...heres the error...invalid expression: unexpected token { in {{category.link}}...raw expression: :href="{{category.link}}"

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass an array of links as a value of the `href` attribute. You can pass [one link](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#edef-A) at the same time, instead.

On the other hand, if we suppose category.link refers to one link only, then you can write this:

```
<a href="category.link">Link</a>
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention i am in a loop...so theres only one link at a time...i have edited my question